# Using IF ELSE in sharepoint calculated value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, infopath

I have a share point form which has 3 textbox fields (datatype=Numeric) as

- "Wellbeing leave balance" which is by default 21.
- Second field is "Remaining balance" which is picks up the leave balance once the leave is applied.
- 3rd one is "Remaining balance will be" field. I want to use a calculated value which will work like lets say IF "Remaining balance" isblank then populate the value of "Remaining balance will be" field else populate value of "remaining balance".

How can I achieve this? any help would be much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Remaining balance]), [Remaining balance will be], [Remaining balance])
```

**Explanation**

It will check if the `[Remaining balance]` field value is **empty**, show the value of the `[Remaining balance will be]` else use `[Remaining balance]` field value.

---

**Update**

I didn't see the InfoPath tag :)

In InfoPath, it's easy to add a `Rule Condition` as the following:

- Select your field,
- Add rule as shown below

[image]

- Select the field as [Remaining balance] and select the value as [Remaining balance will be] from  **Fx** button and `insert field`.

Comment: EL-Qassas Im getting error. doesnt allow me

Comment: Which error did you get? Are you sure you have added the fields name in a correct manner

Comment: i have added the screenshot of my error on my question.

Comment: can you please answer me brother, im watiing

Comment: @Biswa Check the updated answer, don't hesitate if you need further clarification!

Comment: EI-Qassas, i couldnt make it work with the formula but used the rule worked fine . thanks brother.